# How can I do operations on big numbers that can't be stored in one variable

Tags: java, integer

In Java, I would like to be able to do operations on really big integers (that can't be stored in a long), how can I do that?

What is the best way to deal with this, with good performances? Should I create my own data type that contains several long variables?

Example:

```
public class MyBigInteger{
    private long firstPart;
    private long secondPart;

   ...
}

public MyBigInteger add(long a, long b){
    MyBigInteger res;

    // WHAT CAN I DO HERE, I guess I could do something with the >> << operators, but I've never used them!

    return res;
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: lol, I love that you were so close, yet so far, in using "MyBigInteger".

Comment: If you are going to write your own, you could look at how BigInteger works and customise it for your need.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import java.math.BigInteger;

public class BigIntegerTest {

    public BigInteger add(long a, long b){
        BigInteger big1 = new BigInteger(Long.toString(a));
        BigInteger big2 = new BigInteger(Long.toString(b));

        return big1.add(big2);
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(new BigIntegerTest().add(22342342424323423L, 234234234234234234L));
    }

}
```

Comment: Should be using BigInteger.valueOf(long) rather than converting to String and then to BigInteger.

Comment: @ColinD I can't memorize all the API :)

Answer (score 9):

You should check the [BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html) java class. It does exactly what you need.

Answer (score 4):

Have you considered the standard library class [java.math.BigInteger](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html), which supports integers of arbitrary precision?

Answer (score 1):

If you truly need high performance, BigInteger/BigDecimal are not going to cut it.  i used the [apfloat](http://www.apfloat.org/apfloat_java/) library and it worked out very well for me.

Comment: It is interesting that their Apinteger class extends Aprational and Apfloat. I wonder how they managed to achieve high performance with such hierarchy.

Answer (score 0):

If the numbers are gonna be really long I would suggest storing them in a linked list (each node a digit) or a File (in this case io access delays will be there) and then do a digit by digit addition that we used to do manually in our 2nd grade.