# Optimisation of string & conversion operations

Tags: java, integer-arithmetic

I had a go at writing this bit of java code which allows me to add and subtract (large) numbers which are represented using a `String` rather than a **numeric datatype**. This allows me to do basic calculations on numbers much bigger than the numeric data types can handle.

It is a bit rough and ready, I don't perform any checks on the input strings at all for instance, but for the constraints that I am using the code works fine.

I am not that familiar with java library functions (is there something instead of `Character#getNumericValue` that works better?) and I was wondering if there is any scope for improving the execution speed. I guess when the input numbers differ considerably in length, using the '0's to keep the loop running isn't very efficient. Perhaps I am not using a very good algorithm to do this at all. Any pointers would be welcome.

```
public static String addBig(String a, String b) 
{
    // no checks or exception handling at all ...
    String result = "";

    int carry = 0;
    int a_int, b_int, res_int;

    for(int current = 1; ; current++)
    {
        if(current > a.length() && current > b.length()) 
        {
            if(carry == 1)
                result = "1" + result;

            break;
        }

        a_int = a.length() - current < 0 ? 0
            : Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(a.length() - current));
        b_int = b.length() - current < 0 ? 0
            : Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(b.length() - current));

        res_int = a_int + b_int + carry;

        if(res_int > 9)
        {
            res_int -= 10;
            carry = 1;
        } 
        else
            carry = 0;

        result = Integer.toString(res_int) + result;
    }

    return result;
}

public static String subtractBig(String a, String b) 
{
    // no checks or exception handling at all, a is expected to be bigger than b
    String result = "";

    int borrow = 0;
    int a_int, b_int, res_int;

    for(int current = 1; current <= a.length(); current++) 
    {
        // subtract the digits
        a_int = Character.getNumericValue(a.charAt(a.length() - current));

        b_int = b.length() - current < 0 ? 0
            : Character.getNumericValue(b.charAt(b.length()-current));

        res_int = (a_int-borrow)-b_int;

        if(res_int < 0)
        {
            res_int += 10;
            borrow = 1;
        }
        else
            borrow = 0;

        result = Integer.toString(res_int) + result;
    }

    // tidy zeros
    while(result.length() > 1 && result.charAt(0) == '0')
        result = result.substring(1);

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Why not using `BigDecimal`or `BigInteger` ? This would be much easier ;) you have no limit (almost) to the number you can use there. (looking for a link to show you how to use it, this will not really answer you question if I show you how this works) [here is a example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473067/how-can-i-do-operations-on-big-numbers-that-cant-be-stored-in-one-variable)

Comment: You have BigInteger and BigDecimal which allows for, well, _big_ integers and decimals.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic. It might be a better fit for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/, but I believe you'd still get the same response as here (i.e. "Just use `BigDecimal` or `BigInteger`").